# Execute parallell .py scripts

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-module

Say im having scrapper_1.py , scrapper_2.py, scrapper_3.py.

The way i run it now its from pycharm run/execute each in separate, this way i can see the 3 python.exe in execution at task manager.

Now im trying to write a master script say scrapper_runner.py that imports this scrappers as modules and run them all in parallel not sequential.

I tried examples with subprocess, multiprocessing even os.system from various SO posts ... but without any luck ... from logs they all run in sequence and from task manager i only see one python.exe execution.

Is this the right pattern for this kind of process ?

**EDIT:1** (trying with concurrent.futures  ProcessPoolExecutor) it runns sequentially.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import scrapers.scraper_1 as scraper_1
import scrapers.scraper_2 as scraper_2
import scrapers.scraper_3 as scraper_3

## Calling method runner on each scrapper_x to kick off processes
runners_list = [scraper_1.runner(), scraper_1.runner(), scraper_3.runner()]



if __name__ == "__main__":


    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for runner in runners_list:
            future = executor.submit(runner)
            print(future.result())
```

Comment: Please show the code from your tests. Several processes can be grouped together in the task manager, so make sure that you don't miss them there.

Comment: @JohanL added edit 1 , including my tentative with comcurrent.futures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in how you setup the processes. You are not running the processes in parallel, even though you think you are. You are actually running them, when you add them to the `runners_list` and then you are running the result of each runner in parallel as multiprocesses.

What you want to do, is to add the functions to the `runners_list` without executing them, then have them being executed in your multiprocessing `pool`. The way to achieve this, is to add the function references, i.e. the name of the functions. To do this, you should not include the parantheses, since this is the syntax for calling functions and not just name them.

In addition, to have the futures execute asynchronously, it is not possible to have a direct call to `future.result`, as that will force the code to execute sequentially, to ensure that the results are available in the same sequnece as the functions are called.

This means that the soultion to your problem is

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

import scrapers.scraper_1 as scraper_1
import scrapers.scraper_2 as scraper_2
import scrapers.scraper_3 as scraper_3

## NOT calling method runner on each scrapper_x to kick off processes
## Instead add them to the list of functions to be run in the pool
runners_list = [scraper_1.runner, scraper_1.runner, scraper_3.runner]

# Adding callback function to call when future is done.
# If result is not printed in callback, the future.result call will
# serialize the call sequence to ensure results in order
def print_result(future):
    print(future.result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for runner in runners_list:
            future = executor.submit(runner)
            future.add_done_callback(print_result)
```

As you can see, here the invocation of the runners does not happen when the list is created, but later, when the `runner` is submitted to the executor. And, when the results are ready, the callback is called, to print the result to screen.

Comment: still it run sequentially unfortunatly :-(

Comment: Yes, it is due to the call to `print(future.result())`. Let me fix that for you shortly.

Comment: its weird ...  it all makes sense to me your explanations ...  but it still works sequentially

Comment: @JorgeVidinha OK, that _is_ strange, because this works in parallel on my machine (albeit with my own, simple "Scraper" class). How do you set up your Scrapers and what is the `runner` function doing? Is it the first method called after object creation? Are you creating objects for your Scrapers or are they not classes?

Comment: - No they are not classes. runner() method starts a for loop that calls a second method page_scanner(page=1) with page number to scrap as argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181848/discussion-between-johanl-and-jorge-vidinha).

Comment: its now working .... i was leaving the print(future.result()) inside the context manager of with ProcessPoolExecutor. After removing and printing results only from the print_result() it worked as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A subprocess in python may or may not show up as a separate process, depending on your OS and your task manager. `htop` in linux, for example, will display subprocesses under the parent process in tree-view.

I recommend taking a look at this in depth tutorial on the `multiprocessing` module in python: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

However, if python's built-in methods of multiprocessing/threading don't work or make sense to you, you can achieve your desired result by using bash to call your python scripts. The following bash script results in the attached screenshot.

```
#!/bin/sh
./py1.py &
./py2.py &
./py3.py &
```

[image: parallel python scripts]

Explanation: The `&` at the end of each call tells bash to run each call as a background process.

Comment: Well, since the OP has full control of the Python code, it is very possible to make it into a single Python multiprocessing program. Also, even without this, it is possible to run multiple subprocesses from within one Python invocation. This is a very valid way to orchestrate your processes from within Python instead of directly in your shell or as a shell script.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it's not a separate process"? ...  Python's `subprocess` module is used for spawning new processes.  What is the distinction you are making?